# GCP - Cluster and database are turned off, but I am still charged

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Please, I have a problem, that I have turned off my database and cluster, but I am still charged with only small price difference.
Commnand for turning off Cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters resize dev-cluster --num-nodes=0
--zone=europe-west3
```

For database:

```
gcloud sql instances patch app-dataase-dev --activation-policy NEVER
```

[image: My pricing report -- Nothing secret]

The one cluster and Sql database is only one and one. Yesterday 7th Jan., it was whole day turned off and I am still charged for almost same price, like it was not. I am sure that pool was empty and database was turned off. Also check the days before. At 3 - 5. Jan it was running like 5 hours per day and price difference is almost nothing.

I am not able to reach GCP support, because I am not on paid program.

Please could anyone help me find solution for this?

Comment: If you are not using the resources please disable the GKE API and Cloud SQL API and lets see

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried it but it unfortunately saved almost nothing. And Cluster things are still almost fully charged.

Answer (score 0):

From [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing):

> GKE clusters accrue a management fee of $0.10 per cluster per hour, irrespective of cluster size or topology

This is probably the cause of the continued charges you are seeing for your cluster. Although one zonal cluster per billing account should be free according to the same documentation.

I would suggest contacting [Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing), which is available for all Google Cloud accounts irrespective of any Technical Support plan you may or may not have.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will contact them and paste response here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using your Cluster you can delete it to avoid future charges:
[gcloud container clusters delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/delete)

```
gcloud container clusters delete NAME [NAME …] [--async] [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

Same thing for your sql instance, you can [delete your instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/delete-instance#gcloud):

```
gcloud sql instances delete [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

Even though your Cluster has 0 nodes and your instance is not receiving data, they are still using resources that is why you see that charge.

Additionally,  Keep in mind that your Billing report is associated with your Billing Account, and if this Billing Account is linked to other projects that are generating costs, those costs will be reflected in the Billing Report.

To confirm if billing is enabled on a project you could consult the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#confirm_billing_is_enabled_on_a_project)

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I am using cluster and database 3days in week, so I am trying to not waste my money. I have also Firebase connected with this billing account, but in billing details is nothing shocking. 
Thank you, I will think about destroying cluster, when its not used. I have it all in terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Its long responses. I will add only results:

- Its true, that you are billed $0.10 per cluster hour. @Nahuel.
- To disable all paid features you need to disable billing for a project:
  [disable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project)
  then
  [enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project), but **After 30 days with disabled billing, all resources will be destroyed.**
- Also they said, that if you want to keep your project running, and fully turn off, you need to destroy it all.

---

I will go with turning off whole project, which is ok now for me. I have there only dev things. I hope this could be helpful for others, who would like to save some money.

Thanks to responders for help! :)